# Spring boot Pageable sort by a parameter that is not in the Domain object

Tags: java, spring-boot, sorting, jpa, pageable

In our application UI, we're displaying a table of contents that shows user information, i.e.
`firstName`, `lastName`, `email`, `phoneNumber`, `role`, `userType`

The last two columns, `role` and `userType` are NOT part of the `User` domain object. They are derived in the `serviceImpl` class and populated in the `userRoleDTO` object that is being returned as part of the rest call.

In this case, if I want to sort with `User` domain parameters, e.g.

```
.../user-service/api/users-with-roles?size=10&page=0&sort=email,asc
```

it works fine.

How do I make this work with

```
user-service/api/users-with-roles?size=10&page=0&sort=role,asc
```

or

```
user-service/api/users-with-roles?size=10&page=0&sort=userType,asc
```

?

Comment: Where do role and userType come from? and how do you use the sort in your app?

Comment: first we do this: List<User> userRepo.findAll(predicate, pageable); For each user, role and userType are populated using additional logic and are not part of the User domain. Results are placed in UserRoleDTO list.

Comment: So no connection between this two tables? Then sorting is only possible after you loaded the data fully

Comment: There is an indirect connection through a given study. A user can belong belong to a study and have roles for that study. This is what I was afraid of.

Comment: So could do a join?

Comment: User table has a foreign key in customer_user_context table which has a foreign key in study_environment_role table where the roles are kept. User types are stored in customer_user_context table.